# BASH Crear multiples ficheros a la vez con texto aleatorio (diferente para cada fichero)

Tags: bash, random, touch

El texto aleatorio lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

`head -c 100 /dev/random | base64 > file01.txt`

Lo cual me da un resultado así:

```
iyEqUOMYiknQrqvQ11bw1w9baXK2LGfJzEDrPQgSQt79cenylZu0J0q/ztiePiSiP4Bq4sKZxu2q
a81ntTjcfBLlru518AktKN5hf62nhiAfD/lAbhiReIoXHg1wmhkDRuLwtg==
```

Los múltiples archivos los he creado con el comando "***touch***" así:

`touch file{01..05}.txt`

Lo cual me da un resultado así:

```
file01.txt
file02.txt
file03.txt
file04.txt
file05.txt
```

Ahora combino estos comandos para obtener varios archivos con texto aleatorio.

`touch file{01..05}.txt; head -c 100 /dev/random | base64 > file{01..05}.txt`

Pero haciendo un "***cat***" a los ficheros todos contienen el mismo texto.

```
> cat file*                                                                  
Nh5s/KOrhAe5n4R8FKebrd17l/+of5pjPz/itXax1/mdUfGwaCOD7hUOF+gXPHclLLbhFsSEdrYv
rBQoXwu1TvJoNK9whmp1WW9ZAxPBZZPgqmc7NwUkJ08lfkH1PNkarykndQ==
Nh5s/KOrhAe5n4R8FKebrd17l/+of5pjPz/itXax1/mdUfGwaCOD7hUOF+gXPHclLLbhFsSEdrYv
rBQoXwu1TvJoNK9whmp1WW9ZAxPBZZPgqmc7NwUkJ08lfkH1PNkarykndQ==
Nh5s/KOrhAe5n4R8FKebrd17l/+of5pjPz/itXax1/mdUfGwaCOD7hUOF+gXPHclLLbhFsSEdrYv
rBQoXwu1TvJoNK9whmp1WW9ZAxPBZZPgqmc7NwUkJ08lfkH1PNkarykndQ==
Nh5s/KOrhAe5n4R8FKebrd17l/+of5pjPz/itXax1/mdUfGwaCOD7hUOF+gXPHclLLbhFsSEdrYv
rBQoXwu1TvJoNK9whmp1WW9ZAxPBZZPgqmc7NwUkJ08lfkH1PNkarykndQ==
Nh5s/KOrhAe5n4R8FKebrd17l/+of5pjPz/itXax1/mdUfGwaCOD7hUOF+gXPHclLLbhFsSEdrYv
rBQoXwu1TvJoNK9whmp1WW9ZAxPBZZPgqmc7NwUkJ08lfkH1PNkarykndQ==
```

¿De que manera podría hacer que cada archivo tuviera un texto aleatorio diferente ocupando el "***head***" antes mencionado?.

Comment: Favor de leer Cómo formular una buena pregunta

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera lo pude resolver

```
for i in $seq file{01..05}.txt; do head -c 100 /dev/random | base64 > "$i"; done
```

El resultado es este:

```
> cat file*
poiPSfizudlWy9k3Dx/OuDO0aZ+zakMvHJzCxrCkJ3fuL/soat5g5kNb/bPjNWudIpN7ZYK7jIOl
308FmESDhTmd10pYKUnK7JZwhXu54m9iHz7PJUBZvUtmNbfSXwvga8u9ww==
HiFknOLxh+R3JMTpuIjactkSWSWAsNYOOPPETMCZGNKKlVVwkHS3QmkXNhY7wqIK6H08ZuUkpFlU
DxKZvwKjmlS4bm22uWZbHpAbJZKBu73e9OK8VL0gqVnpaVVIoVbVzS9vpw==
EGT4TXnm/LClbyw2wful1/Ow0rV2gF+R91iSxomdQjRoGcaWXFbWulFL+iiedK3Ln284Fn2Nm0fz
Qb6zzbK3e9ijz0Bhojbp3/sc3kkQI9oavwJbElFcuGGaJoX2wHxtYeyeMg==
pSO2WQ0sVZwMrHKnyUh6+R5o6mcV5aor4jGTjpNM4xMuNfxZtKP/fSqQmBQCsGZK1Ce0DouJ2MFP
2tX+yo0OKIdhvYtfawBtjP0RMWTslltVD+rikqbbqnj6A0ebCzVNphTH/g==
zbXQtroFtDDI/kFS0Ns53768Qb5VK2F2+ASCf1TFsIiOWcGCpAhNL4oEo8SyAMO3QyaGdcCnQUgg
KHG14e8jqmvGbBgGlp/4iZ7ecHJG8rbUhXMzI5ZX+rge5j0zFB1SBtDSpQ==
```

Cada fichero tiene un texto aleatorio diferente.